# Iterate over the first n elements of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I iterate up to four objects of an array and not all? In the following code, it iterates over all objects. I need only the first four objects.

```
objects = Products.all();
arr=Array.new
objects.each do |obj|
    arr << obj
end
p arr
```

Can it be done like `objects=objects.slice(4)`, or is iteration the only way?

Edit:

I also need to print how many times the iteration happens, but my solution `objects[0..3]` (thanks to answers here) long.

```
i=0;
arr=Array.new
objects[0..3].each do |obj|
    arr << obj
    p i;
    i++;
end
```

Comment: Are you just trying to grab the first four objects, or are you trying to iterate over the first four objects?  You can use the `take` method to grab the first n objects if you just wanted to iterate over them: `objects.take(4).each do...`

Comment: Why not `arr = Products.limit(4).to_a` (but you probably don't even need the `to_a`)? Any time you find yourself saying `Model.all` you should think again (and then a third time).

Comment: @Yosef you want [each_with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) ... also, `++` isn't a ruby operator

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I guess the rubyst way would go by

```
arr=Array.new
objects[0..3].each do |obj|
    arr << obj
end

p arr;
```

so that with the `[0..3]` you create a subarray containing just first 4 elements from objects.

Comment: Why iterate when just `arr = objects[0..3]` does the same thing?

Comment: this is the ruby way, but I observed it was much slower when compared to iterating over integer index (0 to 3) and fetching element via it (objects[i[). possibly because of copy work

Answer (score 135):

You can get first n elements by using

```
arr = objects.first(n)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-first

Comment: "Hey Ruby, you're slick AF."

Answer (score 20):

[`Enumerable#take`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Enumerable%3atake) returns first `n` elements from an Enumerable.

Comment: How does this differ from `#first`? Can `#first` only be used on an `Array` while `#take` can be used on _any_ `Enumerable`?

Answer (score 6):

```
arr = objects[0..3]
```

Thats all. You dont need the rest

Answer (score 2):

You can splice the array like this `objects[0,4]`

`objects[0,4]` is saying: start at index 0 and give me 4 elements of the array.

```
arr = objects[0,4].inject([]) do |array, obj|
  array << obj
end

p arr
```

Comment: Why `inject` when just `arr = objects[0,4]` will do?

Comment: I assumed the OP wanted to iterate over an array and do something other than just collect the elements.